# utime module missing from micropython on calculator

Tags: python, micropython

I'm trying to create a delay inbetween prints on micropython, but no modules work.

I've tried another suggestion involving `import machine` and of course `import utime` 
both return the error: `ImportError: no module named '[name of the module]'`
Specifically, this is micropython v1.9.4 on the CASIO fx-CG50.

```py
import utime

print("testing time")
utime.sleep(3)
print("there should have been a delay")
```

I expect the output to be:

> testing time

3 second delay

> there should have been a delay

But I just get the error message:
`ImportError: no module named '[name of the module]'`
I've gotten this error for:

machine

utime

time

Note: I’ve tried doing big loops like this. It seems to delay it but it delays and then prints both messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a method to count time without imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007418/is-there-a-method-to-count-time-without-imports)